# How to identify Marker if I use Marker clustering?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

How to identify marker if I use marker clustering, and all that I have it's `MarkerOption` object and it doesn't have tag or id?
Before clustering, I could set tag or id to markers because I created them manually. And I could find an object in DB by this id and change it when I drag marker(`onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)`). Now when I use clustering I don't have id or tag.
And I can't find the object in DB by marker location because `onMarkerDragStart` method gives me wrong location(because marker jump when we have long click on it to help us see it behind the finger).
Sorry for my English.

Comment: By marker clustering do you mean you have several markers on the same map?  And if yes, you want to identify each marker and its methods?

Comment: Yes, I have many markers. And when I drag marker I want to update object in DB which stores information about the location of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all markers and their ids in a hashmap and get their id on any marker method by calling `markerList.get(marker)`.

```
   private HashMap<Marker, String> markerList = new HashMap<>();
    private GoogleMap mMap; //also instantiate your map 

    private void addMarker(String id, LatLng pos){
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(pos);
        options.title("title");
        Marker mapMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        markerList.put(mapMarker, id);

    }
```

Comment: In this case I just can `marker.setId(id)` or `marker.setTag(id)`. You dont understand. Did you use marker clustering?

Problem is that I'm dont add markers by `mMap.add(marker)`. I use `CluserManeger.add(item)`